# undefined reference to `SDL_Init' (undefined reference to `WinMain@16' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status)

Tags: c, clion

I am trying to learn and use SDL on my project.  at first I had some problems where my ide can't find it. I'm using clion ide and mingw. I added the sdl on mingw (C:\MinGW\include\SDL2) and now it's working. But still I can't compile. any idea about this error?

```
Linking C executable Hello_World.exe
CMakeFiles\Hello_World.dir/objects.a(main.c.obj): In function `SDL_main':
C:/Users/Deve/ClionProjects/Hello World/main.c:5: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

this my only code for now

```
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    return 0;

}
```

and I can't make it working.

here is my cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(Hello_World)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)

add_executable(Hello_World ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

my system is windows 8.1 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Did you included .a and / or .lib ?
If you don't include that, your program will never find the functions you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You should include `-lSDL` flag in your cmake file:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror -lSDL")
```